# How to make golden-layout plunker work?

Tags: angular, plunker, golden-layout

I was looking at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/FITTtt?p=preview) golden-layout with angular 2 plunker. The files on plunker are not sufficient to replicate the output. How can I make this plunker runnable?

What are the else config files required to run the plunker? I am new to angular, any help will be appreciated.

I created a quickstart project by : `ng new my-app` and added plunker's file to the project, but am unable to replicate the behavior.

Comment: Did you do npm install?

Comment: yes, I did. I am not sure do I need to need to add any other config files?